# Set bitmap into CStatic object

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc, picturebox

I'm trying to add one bitmap into a picture box. This is what I've tried:

```
void DlgError::Define_Image()
{
    // I generate all requiered elements.
    CBitmap bitmap;

    // Depending on the type of the message, I define the image to show.
    switch (Message_Type)
    {
        case Error: bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_ERROR); break;
        case Warning: break;

        case Information:
        default: bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_INFORMATION); break;
    }

    // I set the new picture.
    m_picture.ModifyStyle(0, SS_BITMAP);
    m_picture.SetBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

I don't know why it's not working. I have the same code I've in some forums. Can anybody help me? I have to define some extra styles?

The picture box has `Bitmap` as its type (Can be hanged in Picture control properties)

**SOLUTION**

I must say that the solution is a combination of both answers. Finally, I define one local variable and I use the next code in order to do what I want.

```
void DlgError::Define_Image()
{
    // Depending on the type of the message, I define the image to show.
    switch (Message_Type)
    {
        case Error: bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_ERROR); break;
        case Warning: break;

        case Information:
        default: bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_INFORMATION); break;
    }

    // I set the new picture.
    m_picture.ModifyStyle(SS_ENHMETAFILE, SS_BITMAP);
    m_picture.SetBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Thanks everyone who helped me!

Comment: Try adding SS_CENTERIMAGE style.

Comment: @EyIM Still not working...

Comment: Use SS_TYPEMASK not SS_ENHMETAFILE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `CBitmap` object as a local variable in the `Define_Image` function.
Once the function goes out of scope, the bitmap is destroyed by the destructor of `CBitmap` object (there are no ref-counts here).

You need to detach the object and then pass the `HBITMAP` handle to `SetBitmap` of `CStatic`.

Fortunatly, only a single line is required:

```
 m_picture.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)bitmap.Detach());
```

Comment: Thanks for teach me about the destruction of the object! Your answer was really helpfull

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that LoadBitmap succeeded?

Isn't m_picture already created with the matching style if not your code might fail.

SS_BITMAP is a number. If you want to change the tsyle of the static control, you need to remove the old style:

```
m_picture.ModifyStyle(SS_TYPEMASK,SS_BITMAP);
```

Otherwise you get side effects.
Check the style with Spy++.

Comment: I tried what you say but still appears as a solid gray rect. I tried to ensure that the method succed using: `ENSURE(m_picture.SetBitmap(bitmap));` and it throws me an exception.

Comment: Is the handle inside bitmap not NULL?

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was really helpfull!